# TypeError: unhashable type python work around?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to update the DiseaseScenario.conn[newKey] which is a set but i keep getting the error not hashable. Is there a way around this?

```
DiseaseScenario.conn={}

    for items in dictList:
        for key,value in items.iteritems():
            flag=1
            for newKey,newValue in DiseaseScenario.conn.iteritems():
                if key==newKey:
                    //***************************///
                  //geting the error Unhashable type                     
                    tempValue=[value,newValue]
                    DiseaseScenario.conn[newKey].remove(value)
                    DiseaseScenario.conn[newKey].add(tempValue)
                    //*******************************************//     

                    flag=0
            if flag==1:
                DiseaseScenario.conn[key]=value

    print DiseaseScenario.conn
```

Comment: DiseaseScenario.conn is a dictionary newKey is string and newValue is a set in which i want to add more element like currently its: { 'Canberra': set(['Sydney']), 'Brisbane': set(['Sydney']) } and i want to change it to {'Canberra': set(['Sydney','Brisbane'), 'Brisbane': set(['Sydney']) }

Comment: Why are you using C-style comments? Python uses `#` for comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put a `list` in a `set`.  You can't do that, because `set` items need to have a fixed hash, which mutable (changeable) builtin python types do not have.

The simplest solution is to just change your `list` to a `tuple` (a tuple is kind of like a list that can't be changed in-place).  So change:

```
 tempValue=[value,newValue]
```

to:

```
 tempValue=(value,newValue)
```

That, of course, assumes `value` and `newValue` are not lists or other mutable types.